# How to insert hyperlink in excel using open XML in c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, spreadsheetml

How to insert hyperlink in Excel using C#? I tried this, but it's not working

```
WorksheetPart workSheetPartss = new WorksheetPart();

 workSheetPartss.AddHyperlinkRelationship(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute), true);

 Excel.SetCellValue(spreadsheet, worksheet, k, i + 1,  workSheetPartss.Uri.ToString(), true);
```